# Unable to find Element on Web page during Automation

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium web driver (2.44) for automation some web pages, there is an unexpected error on my browser during the automation run. Please see the following
image:

[image]

So when this happens, my page hangs and the framework is unable to locate any element in current web page. I tried to upgrade/downgrade my IE driver.

and when i double click on this error sign , following popup IE window comes:

[image]

Comment: I believe your using C# with Selenium. Can you provide some more details about it. Like Browser invoked, Framework and application you are trying to access ?

Comment: @Rupesh: i am automating .net web application.automation is running on IE8,9, & 10 ,framework approach is "Page driven"...the problem is..many time this "yellow" sign appears at the bottom of my IE browser at any random step & then webdriver is unable to locate elements on my page. usually this problem occurs during automation execution.

Comment: Does it displays any mouse hover message on 'Done' message? if yes what it is?

Comment: @Rupesh: second image comes after click on "Done" sign .all these pages (.aspx,.js.,..) belong to application side.somehow i think issue can be from application  side.

Comment: You know... I'm very curious as to how you implement this automation and how your JS loads.  Call me crazy, but I get a feeling that there is a race condition between Selenium and your JS code for the page.

Comment: You have an application bug then surely?

Comment: @B.K:i think it may be a little chance of race condition,because of  singe thread nature of java script,in that case i have to wait for UI response at every action.well ,great suggestion.!!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on browser's protected mode.  It's in the Security tab of the options.  If that doesn't work, make sure that it's the same option (on or off) for every zone.  There are four zones (Intranet, Trusted, Internet and Restricted).

Here's some code that will do that for you (IE):

```
// Intranet
private const string REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_1 = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1";
// Trusted
private const string REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_2 = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2";
// Internet
private const string REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_3 = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3";
// Restricted
private const string REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_4 = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\4";

public static void SetIESecurityToProtected()
{
    // 3 is off, 0 is on
    try
    {
        // Intranet
        if ((int)Registry.GetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_1, "2500", -1) == 3)
        {
            Registry.SetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_1, "2500", 0);
        }

        // Trusted
        if ((int)Registry.GetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_2, "2500", -1) == 3)
        {
            Registry.SetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_2, "2500", 0);
        }

        // Internet
        if ((int)Registry.GetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_3, "2500", -1) == 3)
        {
            Registry.SetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_3, "2500", 0);
        }

        // Restricted
        if ((int)Registry.GetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_4, "2500", -1) == 3)
        {
            Registry.SetValue(REG_KEY_IE_ZONE_4, "2500", 0);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle your exception or record it...
    }
}
```

This is going to modify the registry... so... read through the code and make sure that you understand what it does.  It works for me.  I'm seeing different behavior from different people, but that's what I had to do.

Here's the official requirements disclosure:

1. The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your PATH.
2. On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
3. Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.
4. The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
5. For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

There are a few other considerations, such as the browser window focus that need to be taken into account, so I suggest thoroughly looking through the driver documentation: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Thanks..@B.k for your suggestion. I saved my iedriver.exe file on "VSTS10\Common7\IDE" & i already enable all four protection mode.zoom is also set to 100%.i am not using IE 11 so i think 5th suggestion  is not necessary in my case.

Comment: is there any possibility of memory leakage in IE browser.

Comment: @AdityaK Well, I don't think it would be an issue that would propagate itself through three versions of IE, if it was browser-related.